# What to replace [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated :NO with?

Tags: ios, ios6, qr-code

I am using XCode v.4.6 and I am trying to make an app that uses a QR Code scanner. I have followed a tutorial on this page ( http://iphonenativeapp.blogspot.com/2011/07/qr-code-readerscanner-for-iphone-app-in.html ) and have copied and pasted this code:

```
#import "QRscannerFirstViewController.h"

@interface QRscannerFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation QRscannerFirstViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"First", @"First");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#import "QRscannerFirstViewController.h"

@end
@implementation QRscannerViewController

@synthesize imgPicker,resultTextView;

-(IBAction)StartScan:(id) sender{
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;

reader.readerView.torchMode = 0;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

// EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];

// present and release the controller
[self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];

resultTextView.hidden=NO;
}

- (void) readerControllerDidFailToRead: (ZBarReaderController*) reader
                         withRetry: (BOOL) retry{
NSLog(@"the image picker failing to read");

}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
NSLog(@"the image picker is calling successfully %@",info);
// ADD: get the decode results
id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
NSString *hiddenData;
for(symbol in results)
    hiddenData=[NSString stringWithString:symbol.data];
NSLog(@"the symbols  is the following %@",symbol.data);
// EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
//  break;

// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
//resultText.text = symbol.data;
resultTextView.text=symbol.data;


NSLog(@"BARCODE= %@",symbol.data);

NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[storeData setObject:hiddenData forKey:@"CONSUMERID"];
NSLog(@"SYMBOL : %@",hiddenData);
resultTextView.text=hiddenData;
[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];

}

@end
```

into my .m file. When I put this code ino the editor, I get a warning saying how this

```
[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

and this

```
[self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];
```

has been decapricated in IOS 6.0.
When I run my application and press a button that starts the QR Scanner, my application quits and it gives me the

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

error and highlights

```
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([QRscannerAppDelegate class]));
```

What is recommended for replacing this and how should I fix this error?

Comment: Really? You couldn't figure this one out yourself? If you type that name into the document search in Xcode, and click on the result, it will tell you what to replace it with.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
[self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:Nil];

[reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:Nil];
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea what to do, because I am a beginner coder and this is my first app. Thank you again for not being critical like @Joel

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];` and `[reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`